# how to insert an image in a PDF using iText for .NET

Tags: c#, webforms, itext

I have a table in a database of user records in which there is a column `Profile Pic` that contains images like `~/images/user.JPEG`. I want to export this data to a PDF.

I am using a third party library called iTextSharp, I want to show the image in PDF file in front of user name.  How should I do this?.

I bind grid view with database, it is showing in grid view but when I am exporting it in PDF it showing location of image instead of image.

This is my code, it uses tables and PdfPCell.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)rows.FindControl("imgprofile");
string imagedummy = image.ImageUrl;
PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(id.Text, verdana));
PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(firstname.Text, verdana));
PdfPCell c3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lastname.Text, verdana));

PdfPCell c14 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(image dummy));
t1.Add Cell(c14);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the path to an image, e.g. `imgPath`, you can use that image in a PDF by creating an `Image` object. See the examples of chapter 10 of my book: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C10

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(imgPath);
```

Once you have this `Image` object, you can create a `PdfPCell` with that image as parameter, you can add it to a `PdfPCell` using `addElement()`, you can wrap the image inside a `Chunk`,...

All these different methods, will show a different behavior. That's all explained in [the iText documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book).